# Cannot determine the size of the image

Tags: graphics, errors, bounding-box, size

I have this code in LaTeX, I compile with "latex+dvips+ps2pdf+See PDF"

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure} [h]
\centering
\includegraphics [width=8cm]{CircuitoRC.pdf} 
\caption{Carga de un condensador en un circuito RC.}
\label{fig:circuito}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

In `\includegraphics` it says me this:

> LaTeX Error: Cannot determine size of graphic in `CircuitoRC.pdf` (no BoundingBox).See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... `\includegraphics [width=8cm]{CircuitoRC.pdf}`

I don't know why.

Comment: Can you directly use `pdflatex` to produce the pdf? Otherwise you will need your image in a format compatible with `latex`.

Comment: Latex does not support pdf files, it assure everything is eps and looks for a boundingbox string, then complaining it cannot find one. Use pdflatex instead.

Comment: I have just tried with a .png image, same error

Answer (score 5):

When you are using LaTeX, that is in the commandline

```
 latex myfile
```

you only can use PostScript-File with `\includegraphics`.  PostScript-files usually end in `.ps` or `.eps`.  Using `.pdf` or `.png` will give the error.

In your case, use the following commandline in your shell

```
 pdflatex myfile
```

In that case, you will be able to use `\includegraphics` with the following graphics files

1. JPEG-files ending in `.jpg`
2. Portable Network Graphics, ending in `.png`
3. PDF-files ending in `.pdf`

You should leave the file name ending.  LaTeX will append them as listed above.  This is, to have both an PostScript and an JPEG/PNG/PDF-file, which share the same file name and only differ in the file type and their corresponding file extension.  So you could either run good old `latex` and include the `.ps`-file, while the younger `pdflatex` will search for the `.jpg`, `.png` and `.pdf`-file.